# mysql count total from a field with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

In my mysql database I have a table with this column. The value in this column is like this

Year: 1974,2000,1976,1977

How do I write a mysql statement to select and count total how many of the value above is more than 1997?

My output would be like: 2

```
Select year FROM my_table
```

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT  year 
FROM reg2015 
WHERE cancel is NULL AND mealroom = 'Y' ORDER BY regid ASC
```

and my output is like this

```
year
-------------------------
1974,1976,2005,2008
1954,1958
1987
1946
1956,1959
1944,1946
1974,1975,2005,2007,2001,2002
1971
1978
1955,1969,2000,2003
```

So I like to know how many is greater than 1997 for each row.

Comment: How many rows are in this table

Comment: I have roughly about 200 rows. Year is column. Each row, the values are separated by a comma. So I just need to know how many of "1974,2000,1976,1977" are greater than 1997

Comment: Yes, misread it, sorry.

Comment: Hi, take a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d187/9), and also take a look at [this article](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) hope that's what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this i've used Postgresql, having "id", "comma_sep_string" columns with table name "string_comma", when there is a count it'll show that record and if count is zero it'll not show that particular record and see the screenshot for the output of the given query

```
select temp1.id, temp1.comma_sep_string, sum(count) from
(select temp.id, temp.comma_sep_string, temp.years, count(*) as count
from
(SELECT
ID, comma_sep_string,
regexp_split_to_table(comma_sep_string, E',') AS years
FROM string_comma) as  temp
where temp.years::int > 1980
group by temp.id, temp.years, temp.comma_sep_string) as temp1
group by temp1.id, temp1.comma_sep_string
```

[image: This is the Screenshot]