# Sql-How to compare a comma seperated value in a column with a string

Tags: mysql, sql, json

hi guys thanks in advance.
Actually i am new in SQL. I have one column name grp_member in my group table.
In that value is store in this format: `18,17,16,94`.

When i run this query

```
`SELECT * FROM GROUP WHERE grp_member IN (18)`
```

than i get the result

```
{"Android":[{"grp_id":"1","grp_name":"ggg","grp_created_by":"qsqs@fffg.hhh","grp_status":"0","grp_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","grp_member":"18,17","result":"Success"}]}
```

But when i am trying to give value after the comma then my response is

`{"Android":[]}`

Query is same in only using the next value after the comma.

`SELECT * FROM GROUP WHERE grp_member IN (17)`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the table you're using, and also explain more what you mean when you say "trying to give value after the comma"?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
  `grp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grp_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `grp_created_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `grp_img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `grp_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grp_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `grp_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`grp_id`)
) 
This is my table. I am trying to send member_id from the application and want to check that member id is present or not in the grp_member column. I am using mysql

Comment: refer to the answer in this link, might be helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041242/mysql-count-total-from-a-field-with-comma-separated-values/31053592#31053592

Comment: No 1 tip: Never, ever store data as comma separated items!!! It will only cause you lots of trouble! (One row per value is the SQL way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find_in_set` function, so your query will be-

```
SELECT * FROM GROUP WHERE find_in_set('17',grp_member);
```

Comment: but it is not a good idea to keep multiple comma seperated values in single field as it will not use index and slow the query.

Comment: Thanks Zafar its work for me and i keep your advice in my mind try to avoid the multiple comma  separated value.Thanks for help